# Rebuild opencvsharp without system.drawing to x64

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, system.drawing

Simple as it is, how can I rebuild opencvsharp dlls from the source without system.drawing to x64. I have tried to through each method to eliminate the usability of this dll and its namespaces. but found that it affects the Iplimage and other important classes in opencv. The steps of removing them are not easy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by not using opencvsharp. I only built my dlls from the project I recoded in opencv (c++). It is easier and faster. I copied the dlls (opencv + release version of the project) into the Unity project and it worked.

Comment: I try to use dll on unity AR scene. An unity AR scene project has many folders and files. Which one you used?